# Can someone recommend a laptop that fits my needs?

Tags: laptop, linux, virtual-machines, quiet-computing

As a person who doesn’t buy new digital devices often, I am not familiar with the best choices in the market right now nor with the hardware part of different products.

As a freshman Cybersecurity student, I will have to use a computer (I want a laptop since I have to be super flexible with my schedule, otherwise I’d build a desktop) that allows me to practice. I plan to use it only for programming and CS. My needs are:

1. it has to be affordable (anything below 800€) so not a MacBook or something too professional
2. it must be able to support a VM
3. It doesn’t have to have linux preinstalled but it would be preferable to a Windows laptop
4. it has to be as light as possible, but not with that small a screen (medium size)
5. I’d love it if it was also relatively quiet as I tend to work at night when my partner is sleeping and don’t wanna bother them, and friendly to the eyes as I plan to work for long hours
6. some things I want to do with it are: use VS code for WebDev (html, css, Jscript), java and bluej, install VM, install Python and some extra libraries, use SQL on it etc.

I don’t believe it needs to have too much space, but what I really need help with is this: I have a kind of old Toshiba that was working perfectly with all in point 4, but when I installed Oracle VM i had to dedicate some MB of memory to it and 1 CPU (up to 4 were available but only 1 was suggested as safe) and added Ubuntu in it, it started being very slow. I deleted the VM and restored what I’d given to it, but it’s not been the same. I’m thinking of formatting it, but frankly I don’t believe I can reinstall a VM or change it to having Ubuntu. And there’s always an excuse to buy a new laptop, especially since I last bought one in 2016ish.

Any tips or recommendations?

Comment: I use the Framework barebones with Linux, which fits everything except your budget...

Comment: +1 on the Framework. it might not meet the initial budget, but the OP, over time could easily add RAM or a bigger nvme to make it better.

Comment: also, the total cost of ownership of a framework, over its lifetime, is likely be be lower than any other laptop, due to it's user-serviceable nature.